# C - how to solve Invalid read of size 1 valgrind error

Tags: c, string, server, malloc, client

I'm doing a C exercise that involves creating a client server program with a message exchange between client and server. The exercise text provides a hash table of this type.

```
#define BITS_IN_int     ( sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT )
#define THREE_QUARTERS  ((int) ((BITS_IN_int * 3) / 4))
#define ONE_EIGHTH      ((int) (BITS_IN_int / 8))
#define HIGH_BITS       ( ~((unsigned int)(~0) >> ONE_EIGHTH ))

/**
 * A simple string hash.
 *
 * An adaptation of Peter Weinberger's (PJW) generic hashing
 * algorithm based on Allen Holub's version. Accepts a pointer
 * to a datum to be hashed and returns an unsigned integer.
 * From: Keith Seymour's proxy library code
 *
 * @param[in] key -- the string to be hashed
 *
 * @returns the hash index
 */

static unsigned int
hash_pjw(void* key)
{
    char *datum = (char *)key;
    unsigned int hash_value, i;

    if(!datum) return 0;

    for (hash_value = 0; *datum; ++datum) {
        hash_value = (hash_value << ONE_EIGHTH) + *datum;
        if ((i = hash_value & HIGH_BITS) != 0)
            hash_value = (hash_value ^ (i >> THREE_QUARTERS)) & ~HIGH_BITS;
    }
    return (hash_value);
}

static int string_compare(void* a, void* b) 
{
    return (strcmp( (char*)a, (char*)b ) == 0);
}

/**
 * Create a new hash table.
 *
 * @param[in] nbuckets -- number of buckets to create
 * @param[in] hash_function -- pointer to the hashing function to be used
 * @param[in] hash_key_compare -- pointer to the hash key comparison function to be used
 *
 * @returns pointer to new hash table.
 */

icl_hash_t *
icl_hash_create( int nbuckets, unsigned int (*hash_function)(void*), int (*hash_key_compare)(void*, void*) )
{
    icl_hash_t *ht;
    int i;

    ht = (icl_hash_t*) malloc(sizeof(icl_hash_t));
    if(!ht) return NULL;

    ht->nentries = 0;
    ht->buckets = (icl_entry_t**)malloc(nbuckets * sizeof(icl_entry_t*));
    if(!ht->buckets) return NULL;

    ht->nbuckets = nbuckets;
    for(i=0;i<ht->nbuckets;i++)
        ht->buckets[i] = NULL;

    ht->hash_function = hash_function ? hash_function : hash_pjw;
    ht->hash_key_compare = hash_key_compare ? hash_key_compare : string_compare;

    return ht;
}

/**
 * Search for an entry in a hash table.
 *
 * @param ht -- the hash table to be searched
 * @param key -- the key of the item to search for
 *
 * @returns pointer to the data corresponding to the key.
 *   If the key was not found, returns NULL.
 */

void *
icl_hash_find(icl_hash_t *ht, void* key)
{
    icl_entry_t* curr;
    unsigned int hash_val;

    if(!ht || !key) return NULL;

    hash_val = (* ht->hash_function)(key) % ht->nbuckets;

    for (curr=ht->buckets[hash_val]; curr != NULL; curr=curr->next)
        if ( ht->hash_key_compare(curr->key, key))
            return(curr->data);

    return NULL;
}

/**
 * Insert an item into the hash table.
 *
 * @param ht -- the hash table
 * @param key -- the key of the new item
 * @param data -- pointer to the new item's data
 *
 * @returns pointer to the new item.  Returns NULL on error.
 */

icl_entry_t *
icl_hash_insert(icl_hash_t *ht, void* key, void *data)
{
    icl_entry_t *curr;
    unsigned int hash_val;

    if(!ht || !key) return NULL;

    hash_val = (* ht->hash_function)(key) % ht->nbuckets;

    for (curr=ht->buckets[hash_val]; curr != NULL; curr=curr->next)
        if ( ht->hash_key_compare(curr->key, key))
            return(NULL); /* key already exists */

    /* if key was not found */
    curr = (icl_entry_t*)malloc(sizeof(icl_entry_t));
    if(!curr) return NULL;

    curr->key = key;
    curr->data = data;
    curr->next = ht->buckets[hash_val]; /* add at start */

    ht->buckets[hash_val] = curr;
    ht->nentries++;

    return curr;
}

/**
 * Free one hash table entry located by key (key and data are freed using functions).
 *
 * @param ht -- the hash table to be freed
 * @param key -- the key of the new item
 * @param free_key -- pointer to function that frees the key
 * @param free_data -- pointer to function that frees the data
 *
 * @returns 0 on success, -1 on failure.
 */

int icl_hash_delete(icl_hash_t *ht, void* key, void (*free_key)(void*), void (*free_data)(void*))
{
    icl_entry_t *curr, *prev;
    unsigned int hash_val;

    if(!ht || !key) return -1;
    hash_val = (* ht->hash_function)(key) % ht->nbuckets;

    prev = NULL;
    for (curr=ht->buckets[hash_val]; curr != NULL; )  {
        if ( ht->hash_key_compare(curr->key, key)) {
            if (prev == NULL) {
                ht->buckets[hash_val] = curr->next;
            } else {
                prev->next = curr->next;
            }
            if (*free_key && curr->key) (*free_key)(curr->key);
            if (*free_data && curr->data) (*free_data)(curr->data);
            ht->nentries++;
            free(curr);
            return 0;
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
 * Free hash table structures (key and data are freed using functions).
 *
 * @param ht -- the hash table to be freed
 * @param free_key -- pointer to function that frees the key
 * @param free_data -- pointer to function that frees the data
 *
 * @returns 0 on success, -1 on failure.
 */

int
icl_hash_destroy(icl_hash_t *ht, void (*free_key)(void*), void (*free_data)(void*))
{
    icl_entry_t *bucket, *curr, *next;
    int i;

    if(!ht) return -1;

    for (i=0; i<ht->nbuckets; i++) {
        bucket = ht->buckets[i];
        for (curr=bucket; curr!=NULL; ) {
            next=curr->next;
            if (*free_key && curr->key) (*free_key)(curr->key);
            if (*free_data && curr->data) (*free_data)(curr->data);
            free(curr);
            curr=next;
        }
    }

    if(ht->buckets) free(ht->buckets);
    if(ht) free(ht);

    return 0;
}

/**
 * Dump the hash table's contents to the given file pointer.
 *
 * @param stream -- the file to which the hash table should be dumped
 * @param ht -- the hash table to be dumped
 *
 * @returns 0 on success, -1 on failure.
 */

int
icl_hash_dump(FILE* stream, icl_hash_t* ht)
{
    icl_entry_t *bucket, *curr;
    int i;

    if(!ht) return -1;

    for(i=0; i<ht->nbuckets; i++) {
        bucket = ht->buckets[i];
        for(curr=bucket; curr!=NULL; ) {
            if(curr->key)
                fprintf(stream, "icl_hash_dump: %s: %p\n", (char *)curr->key, curr->data);
            curr=curr->next;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program is executed correctly, but my problem occurs using valgrind when I use the icl_hash_find () function trying to register a client (a string) or trying to check if the client is already registered.

Client and server exchange messages by sending struct of this type:

```
typedef struct {
    op_t     op;   
    char sender[MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1];
} message_hdr_t;

typedef struct {
    char receiver[MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1];
    unsigned int   len;  
} message_data_hdr_t;

typedef struct {
    message_data_hdr_t  hdr;
    char               *buf;
} message_data_t;

typedef struct {
    message_hdr_t  hdr;
    message_data_t data;
} message_t;
```

This is how I register clients or check if they are already logged.

```
char *client_nickname=malloc(sizeof(char));

/******/
client_nickname=realloc(clcan I ient_nickname,strlen(msg->hdr.sender)+1);
strcpy(client_nickname,msg->hdr.sender);

if ( icl_hash_find(hash, client_nickname) != NULL){ 
    printf("%s already registered\n",client_nickname);
}else{ 
    printf("ok %s\n",client_nickname);
    icl_hash_insert(hash, client_nickname, (void*)client_nickname);
}

/*****/
```

and now valgrind output that is repeated several times:

```
==5535== Invalid read of size 1
==5535==    at 0x4C33DC4: strcmp (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5535==    by 0x109FB5: string_compare (icl_hash.c:58)
==5535==    by 0x10A12C: icl_hash_find (icl_hash.c:116)
==5535==    by 0x10A928: threadF (main.c:173)
==5535==    by 0x4E436DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==5535==    by 0x517C88E: clone (clone.S:95)
==5535==  Address 0x54535a1 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 5 free&apos;d
==5535==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5535==    by 0x10A759: threadF (main.c:131)
==5535==    by 0x4E436DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==5535==    by 0x517C88E: clone (clone.S:95)
==5535==  Block was alloc&apos;d at
==5535==    at 0x4C31D2F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5535==    by 0x10A759: threadF (main.c:131)
==5535==    by 0x4E436DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==5535==    by 0x517C88E: clone (clone.S:95)
```

Comment: Is it different from your two other questions about the same?

Comment: This is not really a minimal example. You don't show where you are creating the key. The error is that the NUL string terminator is outside the allocated memory for the key.

Comment: I am prepared to believe that the `icl_hash_find()` call presented in the example is the one about which Valgrind complains, but not enough context is provided to determine the actual source of the problem.  Certainly Valgrind implicates a `realloc()` that is performed a few lines past the end of the program excerpt, and we might need more than that still to determine *why* that causes a problem.  Present a [mcve] if you want help with those things.

Comment: This type of error can happen if your string is not null terminated, and the string_compare goes past the end of the allocated buffer. But, this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
char *client_nickname=malloc(sizeof(char));

/******/
client_nickname=realloc(client_nickname,strlen(msg->hdr.sender)+1);
strcpy(client_nickname,msg->hdr.sender);
```

How do you initilize msg->hdr.sender?. I thought it is zero-value memory inside msg->hdr.sender and strlen(...)  = 0 this case, then make the size of client_nickname still is 1.